# Use a join statement and save the results as a relation like "with" does? - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get data from multiple relationships. But I don't want to end up with multiple queries. So the `with` method won't work for me.

I want to use joins to get the data needed, but laravel overwrites keys if they are duplicated. Is there a way to save the results from a join as a relation. Something like this below (join is incorrect I know).

```
Post::select('post.*', 'category.*')->join('category');
```

If both have an 'id' field it's overwritten by the other. So I would like to have category.* results as a relation so I can call `->category->id` like I can when I use the with method.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the whereHas and orWhereHas methods

Check this link:
http://laravel.io/forum/04-19-2014-many-to-many-to-many-in-wherehas

And Laravel Documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships